# Why the space is so dark even there are billions of stars and many quasars emitting light

Tags: star, universe, light, quasars

In our galaxy itself, there are millions of stars, and there are many more other galaxies in our local group and billions in the observable universes.
For sure they all emit a lot of light, still why the universe is so dark?

Comment: Especially see the answer by JonesTheAstronomer which mentions the CMB.

Comment: Note that the argument I presented reffering to the inverse-square law is invalid because at a large enough scale the universe is homogenous and even though the rate of brightness decreases by the square of the distance, the number of stars increases with distance by a factor of 3.